# Can't erase first page of samd21 microcontroller flash memory

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, cortex-m

I'm using an [Atmel samd21 microcontroller](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/Atmel-42181-SAM-D21_Datasheet.pdf) which has a cortex m0+ core.  To bootload a new program, I want to erase the vector table located at address `0x0000 0000` and write new data there.  I'm encountering two problems:

- Doing an erase on address `0` does not appear to actually erase anything
- I get a hard fault when I try to write to address `0`

I'm going to try changing the address of [`VTOR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0662b/DUI0662B_cortex_m0p_r0p1_dgug.pdf#page=95) and see if that gets me anywhere (**edit:** it didn't help).  Aside from that, does anybody know if:

- There is a way to tell the microcontroller "hey, I know what I'm doing, let me poke this address"
- Is the hardfault upon writing to address `0` something that is defined in the Cortex m0+ spec (I couldn't find anything), or is it implementation defined behavior?

edit

---

My bootloader resides at `max_flash - 0x1000`.  I realize that this might not be the best thing, so I will probably change things so that the bootloader (with its own vector table) resides at `0x0000`.  I'd still like to know why I can't write to address `0x0000` though.  There's nothing in the cortex m0+ documentation that suggests that I shouldn't be able to do that.

I've checked the following things:

- Are my interrupts disabled?  (they are, I've got an `__asm__ volatile("cpsid if");` right before I start poking memory)
- Does changing the value of `VTOR` make a difference?  (it doesn't)
- Is the flash page I'm trying to erase "locked" by [`BOOTPROT`](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/Atmel-42181-SAM-D21_Datasheet.pdf#page=361)?  (it isn't, `BOOTPROT` = 7.)
- Are any regions listed as locked in the [`LOCK`](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/Atmel-42181-SAM-D21_Datasheet.pdf#page=378) register?  (they aren't, `LOCK` = `0xffff`)
- Is it executing from the page it's trying to erase? (nope, the back-trace says that `pc` = `0xf1dc` before the hard fault happens.

Any other things to check?

Comment: In which memory does your bootloader/flash programming code reside? Have you read the app notes about bootloaders for this particular part?

Comment: @Lundin I have not read the app note, because I'm not using Atmel's bootloader, and the only app note I can find is one that talks about using Atmel's own bootloader.  I edited my comment to clarify what's going on.

Comment: I don't remember how to do this specifically at SAMD but as a rule of thumb for all MCUs, it usually doesn't work to execute code from the same flash page that you are programming. Perhaps it is possible to execute code from the RWW page. Hopefully the manual will mention such things, you'll have to read all the dirty details of chapter 21.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the advice, but in my case I'm executing from address ~`0xf000` while trying to erase `0x0000`.  I thought along similar lines at first: "of course, I can't erase the vector table because a fault might need the vector table in order to do its business", but changing the value of `VTOR` thereby invalidating the vector table at `0x0000` doesn't help; a fault is still generated.

Comment: @Lundin I've read chapter 21 a few times, and sadly it doesn't specify what happens when a write to address `0x0000` happens.

Comment: I have written a bootloader for this particular MCU, though it's been a while and I don't remember the specifics. There's nothing magical with address 0, apart from the vector table residing there. You will have to disable all interrupts. But the issue with running code from the same page you are trying to erase is most likely very real, even if the manual doesn't mention this. The first thing to do is to re-locate your code to another flash segment.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the input.  I've checked a few times and I'm 99% sure that interrupts are disabled AND I'm not executing from the page I'm erasing.  __I agree__ that there should be nothing magical about address `0`, but it still behaves funny.  Perhaps the MCU designers decided to make it generate hard faults because that's what a lot of people assumes happens when you try to `*NULL = 0xf00f;` in C.

Comment: Did you test it with a debugger or also standalone? You could try if there are still hard faults when you begin writing from address 0x0004 to determine if it's a address 0 specific problem or a vector table. And on some mcu's it's not only forbidden to erase the same flash page, some have only two flash areas, where you can only erase respectively the pages in the other area

Comment: @jeb I've only tried with a debugger.  It would be really interesting if the behavior was different without, but who knows?  I'll give it a shot.  As to address 0x0004, I can write it fine.  Also, the samd21's flash areas don't work the way you're describing, but thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Atmel (can't blame this on microchip this happened before they were assimilated) went away from their built in SAM-BA bootloader.  Instead they offer a software/source version which you can place yourself and some extra controls to somewhat protect that space but no protection on the protection so it is trivial for a program to unlock and erase or do damage.  So better off either just making your own bootloader, one simpler and easier to maintain, (and try not to erase it) or use the SWD interface which is required as an only solution on competing products if not an alternate.  I eventually went with the latter.

What I found was not only was it easy to erase and write over that space, it was scary easy, once some magic was unlocked you could do simple stores to the space intentionally or accidentally to trash/overwrite.

I'll post my code take it or leave it, been a while since I read the datasheet other than today to see that you should search for BOOTPROT to see about those protection bits and what register to change to disable that protection (if it is even on).

The puts and gets are just store and load instruction abstractions.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include "flash-bin.h"

void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
void PUT16 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET16 ( unsigned int );
void PUT8 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET8 ( unsigned int );
void dummy ( unsigned int );

#define PORT_BASE 0x41004400

#define PORTA_DIRSET (PORT_BASE+0x00+0x08)
#define PORTA_OUTCLR (PORT_BASE+0x00+0x14)
#define PORTA_OUTSET (PORT_BASE+0x00+0x18)
#define PORTA_OUTTGL (PORT_BASE+0x00+0x1C)

#define PORTB_DIRSET (PORT_BASE+0x80+0x08)
#define PORTB_OUTCLR (PORT_BASE+0x80+0x14)
#define PORTB_OUTSET (PORT_BASE+0x80+0x18)
#define PORTB_OUTTGL (PORT_BASE+0x80+0x1C)

#define PORTA_PMUX05    (PORT_BASE+0x00+0x30+5)
#define PORTA_PINCFG10  (PORT_BASE+0x00+0x40+10)
#define PORTA_PINCFG11  (PORT_BASE+0x00+0x40+11)

#define PORTB_PMUX01    (PORT_BASE+0x80+0x30+1)
#define PORTB_PMUX11    (PORT_BASE+0x80+0x30+11)
#define PORTB_PINCFG03  (PORT_BASE+0x80+0x40+3)
#define PORTB_PINCFG22  (PORT_BASE+0x80+0x40+22)
#define PORTB_PINCFG23  (PORT_BASE+0x80+0x40+23)

#define GCLK_BASE       0x40000C00
#define GCLK_CTRL       (GCLK_BASE+0x00)
#define GCLK_STATUS     (GCLK_BASE+0x01)
#define GCLK_CLKCTRL    (GCLK_BASE+0x02)
#define GCLK_GENCTRL    (GCLK_BASE+0x04)
#define GCLK_GENDIV     (GCLK_BASE+0x08)

#define PM_BASE         0x40000400
#define APBCMASK        (PM_BASE+0x20)

#define SYSCTRL_BASE    0x40000800
#define OSC8M           (SYSCTRL_BASE+0x20)

#define SERCOM5_BASE        0x42001C00
#define SERCOM5_CTRLA       (SERCOM5_BASE+0x00)
#define SERCOM5_CTRLB       (SERCOM5_BASE+0x04)
#define SERCOM5_BAUD        (SERCOM5_BASE+0x0C)
#define SERCOM5_INTFLAG     (SERCOM5_BASE+0x18)
#define SERCOM5_SYNCBUSY    (SERCOM5_BASE+0x1C)
#define SERCOM5_DATA        (SERCOM5_BASE+0x28)

#define SERCOM0_BASE        0x42000800
#define SERCOM0_CTRLA       (SERCOM0_BASE+0x00)
#define SERCOM0_CTRLB       (SERCOM0_BASE+0x04)
#define SERCOM0_BAUD        (SERCOM0_BASE+0x0C)
#define SERCOM0_INTFLAG     (SERCOM0_BASE+0x18)
#define SERCOM0_SYNCBUSY    (SERCOM0_BASE+0x1C)
#define SERCOM0_DATA        (SERCOM0_BASE+0x28)

#define STK_CSR 0xE000E010
#define STK_RVR 0xE000E014
#define STK_CVR 0xE000E018
#define STK_MASK 0x00FFFFFF

#define ACTLR 0xE000E008
#define CPUID 0xE000ED00

#define NVMCTRL_BASE 0x41004000
#define NVM_CTRLA   (NVMCTRL_BASE+0x00)
#define NVM_CTRLB   (NVMCTRL_BASE+0x04)
#define NVM_PARAM   (NVMCTRL_BASE+0x08)
#define NVM_INTFLAG (NVMCTRL_BASE+0x14)
#define NVM_STATUS  (NVMCTRL_BASE+0x18)
#define NVM_ADDR    (NVMCTRL_BASE+0x1C)
#define NVM_LOCK    (NVMCTRL_BASE+0x20)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void clock_init ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    ra=GET32(OSC8M);
    ra&=~(3<<8);
    PUT32(OSC8M,ra);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef USE_SERCOM0
//TX PA10  SERCOM0 PAD[2] FUNCTION C  SERCOM2 PAD[2]  FUNCTION D
//RX PA11  SERCOM0 PAD[3] FUNCTION C  SERCOM2 PAD[3]  FUNCTION D
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void uart_init ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    ra=GET32(APBCMASK);
    ra|=1<<2; //enable SERCOM0
    PUT32(APBCMASK,ra);

    PUT32(GCLK_GENCTRL,0x00010605);

    PUT16(GCLK_CLKCTRL,0x4514);

    PUT8(PORTA_PINCFG10,0x01);
    PUT8(PORTA_PINCFG11,0x01);
    PUT8(PORTA_PMUX05,0x22);

    while(GET32(SERCOM0_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT32(SERCOM0_CTRLA,0x00000000);
    while(GET32(SERCOM0_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT32(SERCOM0_CTRLA,0x00000001);
    while(GET32(SERCOM0_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT32(SERCOM0_CTRLA,0x40310004);
    while(GET32(SERCOM0_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT32(SERCOM0_CTRLB,0x00030000);
    while(GET32(SERCOM0_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT16(SERCOM0_BAUD,50436);
    while(GET32(SERCOM0_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT32(SERCOM0_CTRLA,0x40310006);
    while(GET32(SERCOM0_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//static void uart_flush ( void )
//{
    //while(1)
    //{
        //if(GET8(SERCOM0_INTFLAG)&2) break;
    //}
//}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void uart_send ( unsigned int d )
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(GET8(SERCOM0_INTFLAG)&1) break;
    }
    PUT8(SERCOM0_DATA,d&0xFF);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//static unsigned int uart_recv ( void )
//{
    //while(1)
    //{
        //if(GET8(SERCOM0_INTFLAG)&4) break;
    //}
    //return(GET8(SERCOM0_DATA)&0xFF);
//}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
#else
//TX PB22   SERCOM5 PAD[2] PORT FUNCTION D
//RX PB23   SERCOM5 PAD[3] PORT FUNCTION D
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void uart_init ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    ra=GET32(APBCMASK);
    ra|=1<<7; //enable SERCOM5
    ra|=1<<2; //enable SERCOM0
    PUT32(APBCMASK,ra);

    PUT32(GCLK_GENCTRL,0x00010605);

    PUT16(GCLK_CLKCTRL,0x4519);

    PUT8(PORTB_PINCFG22,0x01);
    PUT8(PORTB_PINCFG23,0x01);
    PUT8(PORTB_PMUX11,0x33);

    while(GET32(SERCOM5_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT32(SERCOM5_CTRLA,0x00000000);
    while(GET32(SERCOM5_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT32(SERCOM5_CTRLA,0x00000001);
    while(GET32(SERCOM5_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT32(SERCOM5_CTRLA,0x40310004);
    while(GET32(SERCOM5_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT32(SERCOM5_CTRLB,0x00030000);
    while(GET32(SERCOM5_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT16(SERCOM5_BAUD,50436);
    while(GET32(SERCOM5_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
    PUT32(SERCOM5_CTRLA,0x40310006);
    while(GET32(SERCOM5_SYNCBUSY)) continue;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//static void uart_flush ( void )
//{
    //while(1)
    //{
        //if(GET8(SERCOM5_INTFLAG)&2) break;
    //}
//}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void uart_send ( unsigned int d )
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(GET8(SERCOM5_INTFLAG)&1) break;
    }
    PUT8(SERCOM5_DATA,d&0xFF);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//static unsigned int uart_recv ( void )
//{
    //while(1)
    //{
        //if(GET8(SERCOM5_INTFLAG)&4) break;
    //}
    //return(GET8(SERCOM5_DATA)&0xFF);
//}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void hexstrings ( unsigned int d )
{
    //unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int rb;
    unsigned int rc;

    rb=32;
    while(1)
    {
        rb-=4;
        rc=(d>>rb)&0xF;
        if(rc>9) rc+=0x37; else rc+=0x30;
        uart_send(rc);
        if(rb==0) break;
    }
    uart_send(0x20);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void hexstring ( unsigned int d )
{
    hexstrings(d);
    uart_send(0x0D);
    uart_send(0x0A);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void flash_busy ( void )
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(GET8(NVM_INTFLAG)&(1<<0)) break;
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void flash_command ( unsigned int cmd )
{
    PUT16(NVM_CTRLA,0xA500+cmd);
    flash_busy();
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define FLASH_ER 0x02
#define FLASH_WP 0x04
#define FLASH_UR 0x41
#define FLASH_PBC 0x44
#define FLASH_INVALL 0x46
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int addr;
    unsigned int page_size;
    unsigned int row_size;
    unsigned int pages;
    unsigned int rows;


    clock_init();
    uart_init();
    hexstring(0x12345678);
    hexstring(GET32(ACTLR));
    hexstring(GET32(CPUID));
    hexstring(GET32(NVM_PARAM));
    ra=GET32(NVM_PARAM);
    pages=ra&0xFFFF;
    page_size=(ra>>16)&7;
    page_size=8<<page_size;
    row_size=page_size<<2;
    rows=pages>>2;
    hexstring(pages);
    hexstring(page_size);
    hexstring(rows);
    hexstring(row_size);

    flash_busy();
    flash_command(FLASH_INVALL); //where do you use this if at all?
    for(addr=0x0000;addr<0x8000;addr+=0x100)
    {
        hexstrings(addr); hexstring(GET8(NVM_INTFLAG));
        PUT32(NVM_ADDR,addr);
        flash_command(FLASH_UR); //unlock
        flash_command(FLASH_ER); //erase row
    }

    for(ra=0x0000;ra<0x0040;ra+=4)
    {
        hexstrings(ra); hexstring(GET32(ra));
    }

if(1)
{
    flash_command(FLASH_INVALL); //where do you use this if at all?
    flash_command(FLASH_PBC); //page buffer clear
    for(addr=0x0000,ra=0;ra<(0x800>>2);ra++,addr+=4)
    {
        if((addr&0x3F)==0) hexstring(addr);
        PUT32(addr,rom[ra]);
        if((addr&0x3F)==0x3C) flash_busy();
    }
    for(ra=0x0000;ra<0x0040;ra+=4)
    {
        hexstrings(ra); hexstring(GET32(ra));
    }
}

    return(0);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since pretty much all useful SWD/JTAG debuggers allow you to download and run a program in ram, but not all have built into the debugger support for all the programming the flash nuances, my personal preference is to either have a program in ram that carries a payload which is the flash program and it programs it in application, this way any debugger can be used. That or I write a bootloader if there isn't enough ram for both or use the ram program to burn the bootloader then the bootloader to burn bigger apps.

### Edit

sram.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
    ldr r0,stacktop
    mov sp,r0
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.align
stacktop: .word 0x20001000

.thumb_func
.globl PUT8
PUT8:
    strb r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl PUT16
PUT16:
    strh r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET8
GET8:
    ldrb r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET16
GET16:
    ldrh r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr

.end
```

sram.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0xD00
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

Comment: I'll try this soon, but it doesn't seem to poke the NVMCTRL registers any different than my code does.  Can you append your answer to include definitions of the PUT32 / GET32 functions?  I'm 99.9% sure I can guess what the do, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: perhaps yours is locked in some way that mine wasnt.

Comment: pretty sure mine is/was the samd21 breakout board from sparkfun.  Tried to get into an amazon dash button samd21 but couldnt.  didnt make it to a write protect issue, couldnt get SWD to connect if I remember right, probably the only two samd2x chips I have messed with.